# How to redirect to an MVC action from angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect an MVC action method from angularjs controller. The below line works fine when I test
it locally but the application is deployed, it can't find the resource.

```
$window.location = '/CustomView';
```

I tried below which does not work.

```
$window.location = $location.path('/').$$absUrl + '/CustomView';
```

The MVC controller action is

```
public ActionResult CustomView()
{
    return View();
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a default routing setup in MVC, you need to direct the url to /CONTROLLERNAME/CustomView in order to hit that Action.

So whatever Controller class "CustomView" is inside will likely need to be included in the URL.

Comment: It did not work for me for some reason. I think the angularjs controller needs to know the base path of application as well. Is it possible to access html <base> tag which is defined in the master layout file? Thank you.

Comment: The angularjs controller shouldn't need to know anything more than a URL to send the request to. The first thing to do would be to hit the MVC action directly in your browser. Once you have that figured out, you can then use that same URL in angular. Can you hit the action method? If not, there's a problem in your routing set up. Alternately, is the controller in an area?